# How to run given Python script with class, init and main from cmd?

Tags: python

I'm supplid with script.py file with Python contents of which this is psuedo code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

params = {...}

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, ab):
        self.ab = ab
        self.de = None

    def main(self):
        self.foo()

    @staticmethod
    def DoSomethingUsefull(abc, params=params):
        abc['x'] = abc['Red Fox'].copy()
        return some_list(abc);
    
    def foo(self):
        self.de = SomeClass.DoSomethingUsefull(self.ab)       
        self.de['de'] = "de"
```

I cannot change the contents of the file, just use it as is. Eventually I need to execute the script from external (C#) code, currently trying to run from cmd (Python is installed). My question is how to execute from command line? If it's not possible to execute from command line and a wrapper script is needed, what will it look like?

Using WinPython 3.9.10

Comment: This code has no "executable" code, it just defines a class. Running it on its own will not do anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @DeepSpace said, this file just contains a definition of a class, it won't do anything by itself.

You can create a python file that instantiates the class and calls some of it's methods

something like

```
import SomeClass
ab = {'Red Fox': 42}
myClass = SomeClass(ab)   # instantiate the class
myClass.main()            # call the main method.
```

Bear also in mind that you will need to modify the File at least to correct the typos like `self.de - None` otherwise you won't be able to import the class.

If you are going to modify the file anyway to create the typos (Yeah, I know you said you can't modify it, but you must), you could just make the file "executable" by putting the code outside the class like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ab = {'Red Fox': 42}
    myClass = SomeClass(ab)   # instantiate the class
    myClass.main()            # call the main method.
```

This way you don't need an extra file.

Comment: Is it possible to run from cmd without creating wrapper script (& w/o editing origianl)?

Comment: no, you need code to instantiate the class and call their methods. imagine you have a book in a library, you are asking if it's possible to read the book without picking it up from the shelf and opening it.